# Python httplib2 is not working for authenticated resource

Tags: python, http, urllib2, basic-authentication, httplib2

I have a resource which is authenticated which requires realm, username and password for authentication.
Python's urllib2 has provision to provide realm whereas i did not find any provision for httplib2.
Here are sample codes,
using urllib2 :

```
  auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
  auth_handler.add_password("Protected",
                          uri="http://" + url,
                          user=username,
                          passwd=password)
  opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
  urllib2.install_opener(opener)

  try :
     data = urllib2.urlopen(url, None, timeout).read()
```

Here "Protected" is the realm which is required for authentication.

Now look at httplib2 :

```
req = httplib2.Http(timeout=5)
req.add_credentials(username, password)
response, data = req.request (url, headers={'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip'})
```

In case of httplib2, i did not find any provision to provide realm string for authentication.

Is there a way to add this realm string in httplib2 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `httplib2` is not a must, using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) it becomes trivial:

```
requests.get('http://www.example.com/', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: It works properly at-least in above mentioned case. Thanks. But, what about reliability?

Comment: under the hood it uses httplib + urllib + other built-in libs. `requests` is just a wrapper so you don't have to type a lot of stuff to do common tasks. As such, it is as reliable as the built-in libraries.

Comment: Can you tell me the default value of request TimeOut in case requests module if nothing specific given ?